# String to Datetime onject in DataFrame while ignore empty strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a column `date` in a DataFrame, it is either empty or have a string in this format
`'2021-06-04T15:14:30.512Z'`
I want to convert this to Datetime object but not sure how to handle the empty columns. I want to keep them empty or null but convert the rest.
I tried to use this to convert string to datetime

```
from dateutil import parser
a = '2021-06-04T15:14:30.512Z'
datetime.fromisoformat(a)
```

But unable to use this across dataframe column while ignoring the empty string.
Can someone please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
```

try with `errors='coerce'` parameter in `to_datetime()` method:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],errors='coerce')
```

If you want only date part:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],errors='coerce').dt.date
```